# Nested Elements and Concatenating Classes using Sass

Tags: css, sass, nested

I can't seem to get this to work.. I wonder if this is not doable the way I imagine it or I am just in a state of brain fry at the moment..

I have two blocks of html with classes sort of distributed like this:

```
<div class="my-class">
  <div class="my-class-parent-one">
    <div class="my-class-wrapper">
      <div class="my-class-child"></div>
      <div class="my-class-child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>

<div class="my-class">
  <div class="my-class-parent-two">
    <div class="my-class-wrapper">
      <div class="my-class-child"></div>
      <div class="my-class-child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

My Sass...

```
.my-class {
  &-parent-one &-wrapper &-cell { font-size: 1.15rem; }
  &-parent-two &-wrapper &-cell { font-size: 0.85rem; }
}
```

Should this not be equivalent to this: ??

```
.my-class .my-class-parent-one .my-class-wrapper .my-class-child {}    
.my-class .my-class-parent-two .my-class-wrapper .my-class-child {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Sass will be compiled to this:

```
.my-class-parent-one .my-class-wrapper .my-class-cell {
  font-size: 1.15rem;
}
.my-class-parent-two .my-class-wrapper .my-class-cell {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}
```

Note that there will be no `.my-class` selector in the beginning. To add the `.my-class` you would need to change your Sass:

```
.my-class {
  & &-parent-one &-wrapper &-cell { font-size: 1.15rem; }
  & &-parent-two &-wrapper &-cell { font-size: 0.85rem; }
}
```

Here's more detailed text on the ampersand in Sass: [The Sass Ampersand](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/)

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be correct. For some reason though while I am working in angular it doesn't seem to compile as intended. I am sure I'm just missing something obvious,,

Comment: Well if you are working in angular 2+, then the first thing that pops in my mind, is that you might have problems with [View Encapsulation](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/templates-styles-view-encapsulation/). You can try to turn it off for the component and check whether styles were applied correctly.

Comment: encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None .. I'll have to dig deeper

Answer (score 2):

When you chain an ampersand with SASS nesting it will just use the parent name to continue to the next class. If you want to use the ampersand to include `.my-class` before the continuation you'll need to add a stand-alone ampersand before:

```
.my-class {
  & &-parent-one &-wrapper &-cell { font-size: 1.15rem; }
  & &-parent-two &-wrapper &-cell { font-size: 0.85rem; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your SASS would compile out like so:

```
.my-class-parent-one .my-class-wrapper .my-class-cell {
  font-size: 1.15rem;
}
.my-class-parent-two .my-class-wrapper .my-class-cell {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}
```

http://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/